# Resharper, how to get the name of the class

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

I am trying to write a customized template in Resharper (A plugin for Visual Studio). Can anyone tell me how to get the class name and date using macros?

By the way, where can I find those build-in macros of Resharper??

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'date'? What date are you after?

Answer (score 6):

If your customized template will be a new *ReSharper*'s ***Live Template*** you can use
macro ***Containing type name*** for class name and
macro ***Current date in specified format*** or ***Current date and time in specified format*** for date.